# How to check a string is a beginning of a regx pattern?

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have a regex "abc-def-[a-zA-Z]-ghi". Now I got a string, I want to see if this sting is the first part of this this regx. Below are some expected results.

```
abc // true
abd // false
abc-def // true
abc-def-a // true
abc-def-aghi // true
abc-def-a-ghi // true
abc-def-a-jkl //false
abc-def-a-ghi-j // false
```

Is it posibleAny thought? Thanks.

Comment: You could make the parts optional `^abc(?:-def(?:-[a-zA-Z](?:-?ghi)?)?)?$` https://regex101.com/r/uTbU8W/1

Comment: So even `a` should be a valid match in that case?

Comment: If input testing after each key it this `^a(?:b(?:c(?:-(?:d(?:e(?:f(?:-(?:[a-zA-Z](?:-(?:g(?:h(?:i)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex `^abc(-def(-[a-zA-Z](-ghi)?)?)?$` will do that. The dollar sign at the end makes it match the end of the line. Each hyphen part is optional, and each next part is nested inside group of parens to make sure that the groups appear in that order.

Link to [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/IOdpWT/2)

If you also want to match `abc-def-aghi` (although I assumed that was a typo), you just need to make a small modification to the regex (`^abc(-def(-[a-zA-Z](-?ghi)?)?)?$`)